# Need to add a summary of results to java program

Tags: java, summary

I need to know how to code a summary of results once the user enters "none" to exit the program. Below is the full assignment and the code I have so far.

Assignment: 
Write a Java program the displays the State bird and flower. You should use your IDE for this exercise. You should also use Java classes to their full extent to include multiple methods and at least two classes. The program should prompt the user to enter a State and print both the State bird and flower. The user should be able to enter a State without worrying about case. (e.g. Users could enter Maryland, maryland, MARYLAND or any other possible combination of lower and upper case characters. States may also contain leading and trailing white spaces. Hint: Store the State information in a multi- dimensional array. The program should continue to prompt the user to enter a state until “None” is entered. After all States have been entered by the user, the program should display a summary of the results. You will need to do some research to find the State birds and flowers. Here is a sample run:

```
    Enter a State or None to exit:
      Maryland
      Bird: Baltimore Oriole
      Flower: Black-eyed Susan
      Enter a State or None to exit:
      Delaware
      Bird: Blue Hen Chicken
      Flower: Peach Blossom
      Enter a State or None to exit:
      None
**** Thank you *****
A summary report for each State, Bird, and Flower is: Maryland, Baltimore Oriole, Black-eyed Susan Delaware, Blue Hen Chicken, Peach Blossom
Please visit our site again!
```

//code:

```
public class StatesDataEntry {

   private String state [][] = {
        {"ALABAMA","Nothern Flicker","Camellia"},
        {"ALASKA","Willow Ptarmigan","Forget-me-not"},
        {"ARIZONA","Cactus Wren","Saguaro Cactus Blossom"},
        {"ARKANSAS","Mockingbird","Apple Blossom"},
        {"CALIFORNIA","California Quail","California Poppy"},
        {"COLORADO","Lark Bunting","Rocky Mountain Columbine"}, 
        {"CONNECTICUT","American Robin","Mountain Laurel"},
        {"DELAWARE","Blue Hen","Peach Blossom"},
        {"FLORIDA","Northern Mockingbird","Orange Blossom"},
        {"GEORGIA","Brown Thrasher","Azalea"},
        {"HAWAII","Hawaiian Goose","Hawaiian Hibiscus"},
        {"IDAHO","Mountain Bluebird","Mock Oragnge"},
        {"ILLINOIS","Northern Cardinal","Violet"},
        {"INDIANA","Cardinal","Peony"},
        {"IOWA","Eastern Goldfinch","Iowa"},
        {"KANSAS","Western Meadowlark","Sunflower"},
        {"KENTUCKY","Northern Cardinal","Goldenrod"},
        {"LOUISIANA","Brown Pelican","Magnolia"},
        {"MAINE","Black-capped Chickadee","White Pine Cone and Tassel"},
        {"MARYLAND","Baltimore Oriole","Black-eyed Susan"},
        {"MASSACHUSETTS","Black-capped Chickadee","Mayflower"},
        {"MICHIGAN","American Robin","Apple Blossom"},
        {"MISSISSIPPI","Northern Mockingbird","Magnolia"},
        {"MISSOURI","Eastern Bluebird","Hawthorn (flower)"},
        {"MONTANA","Western Meadowlark","Bitterroot"},
        {"NEBRASKA","Western Meadowlark","Goldenrod"},
        {"NEVADA","Mountain Bluebird","Sagebrush"},
        {"NEW HAMPSHIRE","Purple Finch","Purple Lilac"},
        {"NEW JERSEY","Eastern Goldfinch","Violet"},
        {"NEW MEXICO","Roadruner","Yucca Flower"},
        {"NEW YORK","Eastern Bluebird","Rose"},
        {"NORTH CAROLINA","Northern Cardinal","Flowering Dogwood"},
        {"NORTH DAKOTA","Western Meadowlark","Wild Prairie Rose"},
        {"OHIO","Northern Cardinal","Scarlet Carnation"},
        {"OKLAHOMA","Scissor-tailed Flycatcher","Oklahoma Rose"},
        {"OREGON","Western Meadowlark","Oregon Grape"},
        {"RHODE ISLAND","Rhode Island Red","Violet"},
        {"SOUTH CAROLINA","Carolina Wren","Yellow Jessamine"},
        {"SOUTH DAKOTA","Ring-necked Pheasant","Pasque Flower"},
        {"TENNESSEE","Nothern Mockingbird","Iris"},
        {"TEXAS","Northern Mockingbird","Bluebonnet"},
        {"UTAH","California Gull","Sego Lily"},
        {"VERMONT","Hermit Thrush","Red Clover"},
        {"VIRGINIA","Northern Cardinal","American Dogwood"},
        {"WASHINGTON","Willow Goldfinch","Coast Rhodedendron"},
        {"WEST VIRGINIA","Northern Cardinal","Rhodedendrom"},
        {"WISCONSIN","American Robin","Wood Violet"},
        {"WYONMING","Western Meadolark","Indian Paintbrush"},
    };

   public StatesDataEntry(){

   }
   public String[][] getState() {
       return state;
   }
   public void setState(String[][] state) {
       this.state = state;
   }


}

//second class
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestStatesDataEntry {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StatesDataEntry inform = new StatesDataEntry();
    String states[][] = inform.getState();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Enter a State or 'None' to exit:");

        String state = input.nextLine();

        if (state.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("None")) {
            break;
        } 
        else {
            int index = getStateIndex(state, states);
            if (index != -1) {
                System.out.printf("Bird: %s \nFlower: %s \n",
                        getBird(index, states), getFlower(index, states));
            } 
        else {
                System.out
                        .println("Please try again, an invalid State was entered.");
            }
        }
    }
    input.close();
}

private static int getStateIndex(String state, String[][] states) {
    for (int i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
        if (state.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(states[i][0])) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

private static String getBird(int index, String[][] states) {
    return states[index][1];
}

private static String getFlower(int index, String[][] states) {
    return states[index][2];
    }
}
```

Comment: Storing your state information in a `String[][]` is pretty ropy. Create a class, e.g. `StateInfo`, with fields `name`, `bird`, `flower` (or whatever those fields actually mean - which is part of the point - it's not obvious what `state[5][2]` means).

Comment: Agreed, but the assignment specifically told him to store it in a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Then, after creating the class that Andy is recommending, look at something like HashMap, which will let you store and look up those StateInfos by state name...

Comment: What should the summary be, exactly? Are you just trying to dump out the entire state array to the console?

Comment: @Araymer it looks like the professor is providing that as a hint instead of a restriction.  Jay will be better served by learning about maps and classes, even if it is ahead of the class schedule

Comment: The summary needs to summarize all the results of the user input. I'm unsure of how to use the HashMap, I did try earlier but ended up with errors which I couldn't resolve in a timely manner. Right now, the code runs without errors, but I still need to add the summary. Thanks for all your input.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still not convinced by comments above you can simply store indices you got when user entered state in another collection array/list and iterate through them in the end and print. Same is applicable if you use HashaMap, store keys instead of indices. Or if you go with objects store them in list and print at the end.